# how to open popup box in rails4 link_to

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, popupwindow

Hi I want to open popup box I had given this in my view

```
<%=link_to 'show',edit_interview_round_path(round), :remote => true%>
<div id="popup">
</div>
```

and written this in my controller

```
def edit
  @interview_round = InterviewRound.where(id: params[:id]).first
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

and i am having edit.js.erb

```
$("#popup").html('<%= escape_javascript(render 'interview_rounds/form') %>');
```

in interviews_rounds/edit view have written this

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

in interview_rounds/_form view have written this

```
<%= form_for @interview_round do |f| %>

    <div class='modal'>
      <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'form-control' %>
      <label for='name'>Name</label>
    </div>


    <div class='input-field col s12' >
      <%= f.text_field :question_1, :class => 'form-control' %>
      <label for='name'>Name</label>
    </div>

    <div class='col s12 center-align'>
      <%= button_tag(:class => "btn waves-effect waves-light btn-large custom_btn_gray") do %>
          Submit <i class="mdi-content-send right"></i>
      <% end %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

So now when I click on show it does not open popup it shows edit view on same page I want to show it in a popup box please guide me how to do this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `window.open (<%= edit_interview_round_path(@interview_round) %>, "mywindow","width=600,height=600");` add this line to edit.js.erb

Comment: what error is coming?

Comment: when i click on the link 'show' nothing happens and no error on the console either

also in rails console i got

Started GET "/interview_rounds/54/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-02 18:10:49 +0530
Processing by InterviewRoundsController#edit as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"54"}
  InterviewRound Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `interview_rounds`.* FROM `interview_rounds` WHERE `interview_rounds`.`id` = 54  ORDER BY `interview_rounds`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered interview_rounds/edit.js.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 5.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

Comment: What css u are using for "popup" ??? You just need to play with popup css

Comment: thank you .. i got it finally

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting your partial rendering code thusly:

```
$("#popup").html("<%= j render( :partial => 'interview_rounds/form' ) %>");
```

Looks like you have nested single quotes, which is probably the issue.
Your code is currently set to render the partial on the same page in a div with an id of popup.

If you want to render it in a new window, try something like this:

```
var wind = window.open("", "popupWindow", "width=600,height=600");

wind.document.write("<%= j render( :partial => 'interview_rounds/form' ) %>");
```

If the form is rendering correctly in the #popup div and you need a modal or overlay effect, you just have to style the popup div as a modal and you're good to go.

Comment: it is rendering the form on the same page itself but not opening the popup box

Comment: yes it is opening a new window but i want to open on the same window just like the jquery modal dialog box and show that edit form on the modal dialog box

Comment: Then you just need to use the first code snippet and style the modal. Might want to clarify your question as well. Like @bunty said, you just need to use CSS to style the #popup div.